# API to validate the pointer before use

Tags: c++, winapi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Testing pointers for validity (C/C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551069/testing-pointers-for-validity-c-c)

Is there any simple Win32 API to check whether a pointer points to a valid memory location before using it for write operation?

Answer (score 12):

There is a whole series of `IsBadXXXPtr()` functions, but you should [never, ever use them](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060927-07/?p=29563).

Comment: +1 for everything that refers to Raymond Chen.