# testing for valid pointer in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I wrote a little test to check for null pointer, I simplified it with int and 0, 1, instead of real classes, what I'm trying to test is something like this: `return p ? 1 : 0;`
which in real world would be `return p ? p->callmethod() : 0;`

```
bool TestTrueFalse();
void main()
{
  int i = TestTrueFalse();

}

bool TestTrueFalse()
{  
    int one = 1;
    int * p =&one;    
    *p = 0;  

    return p ? 1 : 0;
}
```

now, you can see, that once the pointer becomes 0 again, the test fails, why?
what's wrong with this? what's the solution?

Comment: i am very confused by the question and the code. if you want to check for a null pointer, `if(p == 0) { ... }` should be good enough, right? Your code does not use consistent data types (bool vs. int) and it just doesn't make much sense either.

Comment: I don't see how the test can fail, you never set the pointer to null. The test should succeed.

Comment: @tenfour: "if(p == 0) { ... } should be good enough, right?" `if(!p){...}` should be good enough...

Comment: bool shouldn't be treated as integer. You should return true/false, not 1/0

Comment: @SigTerm: While I agree with you, it is purely a point of style. C++ has a well defined conversion from integers to `bool` so there's nothing technically wrong with returning `1` and `0`.

Comment: @Charles:  While it's a point of style, I think it a significant one.  While this confusion won't cause the compiler to do anything unexpected, mixing `bool` and `int` doesn't work in general, even if limited to values of 0 and 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
*p = 0;
```

you probably meant

```
p = 0;
```

*p = 0 sets what the pointer points to, not the pointer

Answer (score 1):

When testing a pointer value with a conditional in C++, it will return true if the value is non-zero and false if the value is 0.  In your sample `p` is slated to point at the local `one` and hence has a non-zero address (even though the value at the address is 0).  Hence you get true

Answer (score 1):

A null pointer is a pointer which points to the address 0, not the value 0.

To set a pointer to null, do:

```
p = 0;
```

To elaborate, your code sets the pointed-to-int to 0. For example:

```
int i = 1;
int *p = &i;
assert(*p == 1); //p points to 1

*p = 0;
assert(*p == 0 && i == 0); //p points to the same location, but that location now contains 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The code `*p = 0;` does not set the pointer to null. It sets what p is pointing to zero.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is an address in memory.  `int *p = &one;` takes the address of the variable `one`, and stores it in `p`.  `*p = 0;` stores 0 in the memory pointed to by `p`, meaning that the value of `one` is now 0.  So, you have changed what `p` points to, but not `p` itself.  `TestTrueFalse()` will return 1.

Answer (score 0):

> to test it for a null pointer before inspecting the value pointed to you might use code like

`if(ip != NULL)`

taken from http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10d.html

`NULL` might be safer in your code, as it is more compiler independent than just writing `0`. and it might also be more clear for others to read in your code.

Comment: this might also be useful here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/551069/testing-pointers-for-validity-c-c

Comment: NULL, in C++, is required to be 0.  Any compiler that treats the two at all differently is not a C++ compiler.  The advantage of NULL is that it signifies that it's supposed to be a pointer value, but the disadvantage is that it can be misleading.  (I'm really looking forward to `nullptr` in the next C++ standard.)