# Visual Studio trigger a breakpoint, if the pointer is pointing to invalid memory

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm working with visual studio IDE, I need to break my program at a particular place if a pointer at the same line pointing to a invalid memory (already deleted memory). is there a way to do that?

Comment: You cannot do this inside your actual C++ code, q.v. [this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202570/c-is-it-possible-to-determine-whether-a-pointer-points-to-a-valid-object), and I suspect you also won't be able to do it in the debugger.

Comment: Microsoft's Debug CRT will basically do this for you. When memory is deallocated it is overwritten with `0xDD` so that you and the debugger can tell it shouldn't be used. [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx) for what `0xFD` and `0xCD` mean.

Answer (score 1):

If you control the type pointed to, yes.

Add a field `int already_destroyed` and set it to `0` in the constructors, and to a nonzero value in the destructor. Even if the debug CRT overwrites it, it still will be non-zero. In Visual Studio, use a conditional breakpoint with condition `already_destroyed != 0`.

Theoretically non-portable, but I suspect the idea will work in more environments.

Answer (score 0):

As [this Stack Overflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202570/c-is-it-possible-to-determine-whether-a-pointer-points-to-a-valid-object) discusses, you cannot determine whether a pointer is valid or not in your C++ code.  The main reason for this is that there would be a lot of overhead in maintaining the state of each pointer.  The Visual Studio debugger uses C++ code for its functionality, so the same holds true there.  That being said, you *can* monitor the memory to which each of your pointers is pointing, by either typing the pointer name in the watch list, or inputting it in the Memory window `(Debug -> Windows -> Memory)`.  However, note that the pointer itself won't necessarily tell whether the memory it points to is valid or invalid.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a kind of "post mortem" solution, there is always the possibility of using PageHeap. This way, if your program tries to access free'd or otherwise invalid memory, the CRT will cause a __debugbreak. But be aware that this solution will bloat your memory consumption so don't forget to disable it afterwards!

All informations you need:
[PageHeap @ MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549561%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)