# How do you find out if memory that was dynamically allocated is emptied?

Tags: c++, qt-creator, dynamic-programming

I am currently doing some dynamic programming in C++ using QT creator. Is there a way to know if a piece of memory that I allocated dynamically is emptied out at the end of a function?

EDIT: I am trying to find if the memory is emptied after I attempted to deleted. Not check if a pointer is valid.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you what to do?

Comment: Please provide how you are allocating memory. If you are using malloc/calloc,then check for return value against null.

Comment: Are you sure that you're doing [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)?

Comment: If youre' wondering if there is a (standard) way to determine whether a particular part of memory has been deallocated, then no. You can avoid that problem through the use of smart pointers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Is it possible to determine whether a pointer points to a valid object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202570/c-is-it-possible-to-determine-whether-a-pointer-points-to-a-valid-object)

Comment: If you allocated the memory using malloc() . You should define your own free () function so that you can set the pointer to NULL after freeing it. In this way you can check whether pointer is valid pointer or not before accessing it. Similarly you should count total number of references to a variable in c++ and delete that pointer after reference count reach to zero. Don't forget to set the pointer to NULL.

Comment: @NathanOliver I have a virtual pure class 'obstacle', and there are two classes that inherit from it: circle and polygone.  In another class, I have a vector of pointers to 'obstacle', and I fill it up using functions that dynamically create the obstacles.

Comment: What do you mean by "emptied"?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I mean it was deleted.

Comment: I really sugest you use a `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` and leave the memory management to the instance itself.  Then when you erase the element from the vector it is handled correctly and nothing else needs to be done by you.

Comment: If you allocated it dynamically (`new`) and if you used `delete` then it is deleted...

Answer (score 1):

Well, I assume you mean "released" instead of "emptied".

If you have a pointer variable, always set "nullptr" to it at the begining.
If you release the pointer, always set "nullptr" to it.

You can always check, if the pointer is equal to nullptr, of so, it's released.
There is no simple way how to check, if an address contains a valid object.