# How to check validity of a C pointer in C#?

Tags: c#, memory-management, unmanaged-memory

An unmanaged pointer is passed to a method of a class in C#. Before manipulating, I need to make sure that the pointer is allocated with the claimed size and is still valid (not freed yet). How is it possible?

Comment: You can't. It sounds like the C code is buggy.

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Longer answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551069/testing-pointers-for-validity-c-c

Comment: In Windows programming, we've some tools like functions like IsBadReadPtr. Can't such tools help?