# Is this a good replacement for isBadWritePtr()

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-management, heap-memory, heap-corruption

I saw the code below in @constm answer to this question,

[Most efficient replacement for IsBadReadPtr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496034/most-efficient-replacement-for-isbadreadptr/496063)

```
bool IsBadReadPtr(void* p)
{
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi = {0};
if (::VirtualQuery(p, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)))
{
    DWORD mask = (PAGE_READONLY|PAGE_READWRITE|PAGE_WRITECOPY|PAGE_EXECUTE_READ|PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE|PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY);
    bool b = !(mbi.Protect & mask);
    // check the page is not a guard page
    if (mbi.Protect & (PAGE_GUARD|PAGE_NOACCESS)) b = true;

    return b;
}
return true;
}
```

I am using Windows and coding in Visual Studio 2013. The code looks fine to me and I can see that it would overcome the problem in `isBadReadPtr` of accessing page guards, but I would like to understand how it would overcome the problem of multi-threading?

Is this code a good substitute for `isBadReadPtr`? Also looks like this code should return `false` for me to understand that the `ptr` I pass is valid.

Also if I pass a object of a class, how does it know the size of the object and check the whole space? Maybe I didnt understand VirtualQuery well.

Please let me know if what I understood is right.

TIA!

Comment: fyi: Old New Thing: "IsBadXxxPtr should really be called CrashProgramRandomly" https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060927-07/?p=29563

Comment: @RichardCritten, yes I am aware of that. Thats the reason I am looking for an fixed alternative. This is alternative fine?\

Comment: There's not going to be a "fix". It's not broken. Did you read and understand the *logic* behind Raymond's post?

Comment: Updated link to Raymond's post: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060927-07/?p=29563

Comment: Yes, I added this code to my app, and it did detect a bad pointer.