# Intel Pin: correctly continuing execution after RECEIVED_ACCESS_FAULT exception

Tags: c++, profiling, intel-pin

In one of my analysis routines I received as input a `void*` pointer, which may or not may be a "good" pointer to a string.

To check the case of a bad pointer I use the IsBadPointer variant proposed here [Most efficient replacement for IsBadReadPtr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496034/most-efficient-replacement-for-isbadreadptr)

However, this is not completely reliable. So, I wanted to catch the RECEIVED_ACCESS_FAULT exception raised when it is tried to deference a bad pointer, change the value of the pointer to a good value and then continue with the execution.

So, to try this out I deferenced a global NULL pointer (`string_pointer`) in my analysis routine and I set the exception handler as follows:

```
    EXCEPT_HANDLING_RESULT ExceptionHandler(THREADID tid, EXCEPTION_INFO *pExceptInfo, PHYSICAL_CONTEXT *pPhysCtxt, VOID *v)
{
    EXCEPTION_CODE c = PIN_GetExceptionCode(pExceptInfo);
    EXCEPTION_CLASS cl = PIN_GetExceptionClass(c);
    std::cerr << "Exception class " << cl << endl;
    std::cerr << PIN_ExceptionToString(pExceptInfo) << endl;

    //Change string_pointer contents from NULL
    string_pointer = "<Invalid Memory>";

    return EHR_HANDLED;
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work as the pin tool gets stucked in the exception handler. Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Pin won't catch faults thrown in analysis code. You should use Hadi's solution and look for the terminating NULL yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always access application memory from your analysis routines using [PIN_SafeCopy()](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97503/Pin/html/index.html#SafeCopy), which is [declared](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97503/Pin/html/group__PIN__CONTROL.html#ga98669d2f5629027689d60bd852ffa0eb) as follows:

```
size_t LEVEL_PINCLIENT::PIN_SafeCopy(VOID* dst, const VOID* src, size_t size)
```

The function returns the number of bytes successfully copied from the source buffer. So you can compare it to `size` to determine whether it was fully successful or not. `PIN_SafeCopyEx()` is a similar function that provides additional information in case of failure.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how long the string is supposed to be in advance. That's why I ruled out safe copy and instead tried to solve this issue via exception handling.

Comment: @Simus  You can still use `PIN_SafeCopy` in a loop until it returns zero. Although that seems wrong to me that you don't know the size. You should know the size or there should be some terminating character.

Comment: or until the returned value is smaller than `size`.